# How to handle NILs with Anemone / Nokogiri web scraper?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, scraper, anemone

```
def scrape!(url)   
  Anemone.crawl(url) do |anemone|   
     anemone.on_pages_like %[/events/detail/.*] do |page|   
      show = {   
        headliner: page.doc.at_css('h1.summary').text,   
        openers: page.doc.at_css('.details h2').text
       }   
      puts show   
    end   
  end   
end
```

Writing a scraper in Anemone, which uses Nokogiri under the hood..

Sometime the selector `.details h2'`returns nothing because its not in the HTML, and calling `text` on it throws an exception.

I'd like to avoid if/elses all over the place...

```
   if page.doc.at_css('.details h2').empty?   
      openers: page.doc.at_css('.details h2').text
   end
```

Is there any more eloquent way of handling errors produced by inconsistant mark up? For instance CoffeeScript has the existentional operator `person.name?.first()`. If the HTML has the element, *great* make the object and call text on it. If not, move on and dont add it to the hash.

Comment: What do you want to do? Ignore them?

Comment: Just like with any other code: check if a value is `nil` and don't continue (or otherwise react accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

You just need do:

```
anemone.on_pages_like %[/events/detail/.*] do |page|   
      if not page.nil?
         ...#your code
      end
end
```